# Example involving convergent/divergent series

Tags: calculus

I was just curious...
How would we give an example of a series $\sum a_n$ of positive terms and a divergent series $\sum b_n$ such that $a_n\geq b_n$ for all $n$, but $\sum a_n$ converges.
Thanks.

Comment: The question needs editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $b_n=-1$ for $n \in \mathbb N.$